# CSS/AJAX - Activate style on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a search feature which uses AJAX to populate the search result field. I want to style each search result as it gets added in with some effect (like a "loading-in-animation"). I currently have this code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/Search',
  data: {
    'search_value': str
  },
  dataType: 'text',
})
.done(function(json) {
  var Search = JSON.parse(json), searchHTML = '', x;
  for (x in Search) {
    $('<span id="item'+x+"' class="search-item" style="display: none;">'+  Search[x] + '</span>').appendTo('#main').show('slow');
  }
});
```

this works, however `.show()` I have found is a bit performance heavy and so as such wanted to lessen how much performance used to animate the loading of each search results.

I tried setting up this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/Search',
  data: {
    'search_value': str
  },
  dataType: 'text',
})
.done(function(json) {
  var Search = JSON.parse(json), searchHTML = '', x;
  for (x in Search) {
    $('<span id="item'+x+"' class="search-item off" style="display: none;">'+  Search[x] + '</span>').appendTo('#main').removeClass('off');
  }
});
```

then my CSS for this is:

```
.search-item{
  max-height: 256px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 3s;
}
.search-item.off{
  max-height: 0px;
}
```

by doing this it removes the off immediately, which then uses the `transition` CSS attribute to make it grow over 3 seconds (just a testing time - it will probably be something like `0.5s` or something).

The only problem is that it is just removing the class but no transition effect happens (if I remove the `removeClass()` code and then remove the class using firebug or another dev tool. it works fine).

**Does anyone know how to fix this and get it so that the `transition` attrib applies and the results don't instantly get displayed?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It removes the class before the element is even added to the DOM, use a timeout of some sort to defer the removing of the class until after the element is inserted.
I'd prefer the native `setTimeout`, but jQuery has `queue()` and `delay()` that can be used to create the same effect.

```
$.ajax({
  type  : 'GET',
  url   : '/Search',
  data  : {
    'search_value': str
  },
  dataType : 'json'
}).done(function(json) {

    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
        var span = $('<span />', {
           id      : 'item' + key,
           'class' : 'search-item off',
           style   : 'display : none',
           text    : value
        }).appendTo('#main');

        setTimeout(function() {
            span.removeClass('off')
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: wow works great! Now I just need to get it to add more than just one line (I have a dropdown feature in my search functions) and should be great! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: changed the `text` to `html` to allow further html nesting and it is perfect! Thanks!